# CSS focus outline not removed with focus-visible polyfill [NextJS]

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I'm using [focus-visible polyfill](https://github.com/WICG/focus-visible), that way mouse events on clickable elements such as `button` won't trigger the focus outline.

However on NextJS, a Server Side Render Framework, the focus outline still appears when clicking on button elements. I've used this library in client frameworks such as create-react-app, and I had no issues.

focus-visible is loaded by `_app.js` page

```
import "focus-visible";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

Tried loading focus-visible inside `_document.js` page, didn't make a difference.

The css used by both demos.

```css
// removes outline when clicking
.js-focus-visible :focus:not(.focus-visible) {
  outline: none;
}

button {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

// displays when focusing with keyboard
button.focus-visible {
  color: red;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

[Demo: focus-visible removes outline on create-react-app upon clicking](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/aquaductape/cra-focus-visible)

[image: Screenshot from 2020-06-22 21-47-37]

[Demo: focus-visible fails to remove outline on NextJS upon clicking](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/aquaductape/next-focus-visible)

[image: Screenshot from 2020-06-22 21-46-28]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wasn't with NextJS but the scoped CSS library [styled-jsx](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx/issues/424).

The solution was using the one-off global selector.

For some reason using the Global style fails, but using the one-off global selector works.

Global style fails

```js
<style jsx global>{`
  .js-focus-visible :focus:not(.focus-visible) {
    outline: none;
  }
`}</style>
```

But One-off global selector works

```js
<style jsx>{`
  :global(.js-focus-visible) :focus:not(.focus-visible) {
    outline: none;
  }
`}</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `<a href="abc.com" class="abc">` instead of `<button>`

Comment: For this case I won't be switching "button" with any other elements.